# Google Earth Engine finds Sentinel-3 images with no intersect with defined ROI

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, search, sentinel-3

When I search for Sentinel-3 images that have been captured over a small lake, GEE returns images with no intersect with defined ROI. This behavior is just observed when searching for images captured in 2021 (last year), and everything is fine with the years before (2016-2020). Below is my code:

```
//Create Filters
var summer2016 = ee.Filter.date('2016-05-01','2016-11-01');
var summer2017 = ee.Filter.date('2017-05-01','2017-11-01');
var summer2018 = ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01','2018-11-01');
var summer2019 = ee.Filter.date('2019-05-01','2019-11-01');
var summer2020 = ee.Filter.date('2020-05-01','2020-11-01');
var summer2021 = ee.Filter.date('2021-05-01','2021-11-01');

var allSeasonsFilter = ee.Filter.or(summer2021);

var c = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI")
  .filter(allSeasonsFilter)
  .filterBounds(geometry);


var band = ee.Image(ee.List(c.select('quality_flags').toList(999)).get(0))
print(band)
Map.addLayer(band, [], 'quality_flags', true);
```

When searching for 2020 data, everything is fine and GEE finds the images containing my ROI (small polygon of the lake):
[image]

But, when searching for 2021 images, it finds images not containing the ROI:
[image]

Comment: FYI Something is wrong with GEE's ingestion of S-3 data since 2021.  Bands 1 and 10 contain nonsense very low negative values instead of valid data. No word on when or if this will be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Earth Engine is concerned, that image *does* intersect your ROI.  If I run

```js
Map.addLayer(band.geometry());
```

then I get this picture:

[image: screenshot of geometry]

All of those black pixels in your image are, in fact, pixels which are within the bounds of the image. I'm not familiar with the `COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI` dataset so I can't tell you whether this is inherent to the dataset or a processing error.

There are a number of possible approaches, depending on what your needs are; all of them will involve processing multiple images, rather than picking just one after `filterBounds`.

One approach is to combine multiple images, taking whichever ones have “good pixels” according to your criterion, or taking some average of them. Of course, this means you no longer have pixels all from the same moment in time. Another method would be to filter the image collection according to whether all the pixels *in a specific image* are good. I'll show you how to do that.

```js
var c = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI")
  .filter(allSeasonsFilter)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(function(image) {
    // These unwanted pixels seem to have quality_flags = 0, so test for that.
    // (That doesn't seem to match the dataset documentation, though.)
    var bad = image.select('quality_flags').eq(0).rename('bad');
    // Count 'bad' pixels that are inside the ROI by summing the comparison.
    var badCount = bad.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry).get('bad');
    // Mask out any bad pixels, *and* put the count as a property on the image
    return image.updateMask(bad.not()).set('badCount', badCount);
  });
```

We map over the candidates returned by `filterBounds()` to process them individually. By using the Inspector I observed that the unwanted pixels were all ones which had a `quality_flags` value of 0 (which is odd; it seems like they ought to have some of the flags *set* since they are documented to indicate various flaws, not goodness). So, `var bad = image.select('quality_flags').eq(0).rename('bad');` identifies those pixels. Then, we use `reduceRegion()` to sum up the bad values (`.eq(0)` produces an image which is 1 where the condition is met and 0 where it does not), and use `set()` to attach that as a property on the image. We can also remove those pixels at the same time using `updateMask()`.

Now that we can identify undesirable images, we can filter them out:

```js
var precise = c.filter(ee.Filter.eq('badCount', 0));
print(c.size(), precise.size());  // printed 595, 255
```

Then you can pick an image from this collection. Note that `toList` is an inefficient way to work with a collection and should be avoided whenever possible; to get the first image you can just use `.first()`.

```js
var band = precise.first().select('quality_flags');
```

Putting it all together, here's your code with my changes:

```js
//Create Filters
var summer2016 = ee.Filter.date('2016-05-01','2016-11-01');
var summer2017 = ee.Filter.date('2017-05-01','2017-11-01');
var summer2018 = ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01','2018-11-01');
var summer2019 = ee.Filter.date('2019-05-01','2019-11-01');
var summer2020 = ee.Filter.date('2020-05-01','2020-11-01');
var summer2021 = ee.Filter.date('2021-05-01','2021-11-01');

var allSeasonsFilter = ee.Filter.or(summer2021);

var c = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI")
  .filter(allSeasonsFilter)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(function(image) {
    // These unwanted pixels seem to have quality_flags = 0, so test for that.
    // (That doesn't seem to match the dataset documentation, though.)
    var bad = image.select('quality_flags').eq(0).rename('bad');
    // Count 'bad' pixels that are inside the ROI by summing the comparison.
    var badCount = bad.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry).get('bad');
    // Mask out any bad pixels, *and* put the count as a property on the image
    return image.updateMask(bad.not()).set('badCount', badCount);
  });

// Filter to only images that have no 'bad' pixels,
// as defined by the preceding map operation.
var precise = c.filter(ee.Filter.eq('badCount', 0));
print(c.size(), precise.size());

var band = precise.first().select('quality_flags');
print(band);
Map.addLayer(band, [], 'quality_flags', true);
Map.addLayer(band.geometry());
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d04eee834733fdccc6b8dcfc0e6ee048

To improve on this further, you might want to filter with specific `quality_flags` bits instead of just looking for `quality_flags` not equal to zero. I'll leave that to you — it's just a matter of changing the condition from `image.select('quality_flags').eq(0)` to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, for the great, well-documented solution!